# Deep filtering in hierarchical object

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have a hierarchical javascript object, which I need to filter out some of its elements. I wonder if there is an easy way to do this.

For example I have an object `actions` as below. I want to filter out those that have an `default` property which is set to `true`.

```
let actions={
  sql: [
  {
    content: 'aaa',
    default: true
  },
  {
    stmt: 'bbb'
  },
  {
    stmt: 'ccc',
    default: true
  }],
  email: [
  {
    content: 'xxx',
    default: true
  }]
}
```

So eventually I want to have something like:

```
let filteredActions={
  sql: [
  {
    stmt: 'bbb'
  }
  ],
  email: []
}
```

This how I try to solve my problem, but seems it does not work.

```
getNonDefaultActions = actions =>
  map(actions, (actionListByType, key) => {
    actionListByType.filter(action => !(action.defaultFlag === true))
});
```

It seems nothing has been filtered. Any solution is welcome. Additionally, if lodash provides something handy for this type of problem that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lodash's [`_.mapValue()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mapValues) with [`_.reject()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#reject):

```js
const actions = {"sql":[{"content":"aaa","default":true},{"stmt":"bbb"},{"stmt":"ccc","default":true}],"email":[{"content":"xxx","default":true}]}

const result = _.mapValues(actions, arr => _.reject(arr, 'default'))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.entries(actions).forEach(([k, v]) => actions[k] = v.filter(f => !f.default));` does the trick in vanilla. The idea is to iterate through key-value object pairs and reassign each value to a filtered version of itself.

```js
const actions = {"sql":[{"content":"aaa","default":true},{"stmt":"bbb"},{"stmt":"ccc","default":true}],"email":[{"content":"xxx","default":true}]};

Object.entries(actions).forEach(([k, v]) => actions[k] = v.filter(f => !f.default));
  
console.log(actions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get a new object with filtered properties.

```js
let actions = { sql: [{ content: 'aaa', default: true }, { stmt: 'bbb' }, { stmt: 'ccc', default: true }], email: [{ content: 'xxx', default: true }] },
    result = Object.assign(
        ...Object
            .entries(actions)
            .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v.filter(o => o.default !== true) }))
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Happy new year :)

Comment: @OriDrori, happy new year to you, too :)